# ServiceStack Bug serializing GUIDs, numbers, etc. when value is default and SerializeFn is specified

Tags: servicestack

When you try and serialize a Guid that is empty (not null, but empty) the result will be omitted if you set ExcludeDefaultValues = true.
But, if you then set ExcludeDefaultValues = false it will generate the string ""

```csharp
JsConfig.IncludeNullValues = false;
JsConfig.ExcludeDefaultValues = false;
var tt = new { Name="Fred", Value=Guid.Empty, Value2=Guid.NewGuid() };
var test = JSON.stringify(tt);
Console.WriteLine(test);
```

Gives

`{"Name":"Fred","Value":"00000000000000000000000000000000","Value2":"598a6e08af224db9a08c2d0e2f6cff11"}`

But we want the Guid's formatted as a Microsoft format Guid at the client end, so we add a serializer:

```csharp
JsConfig.IncludeNullValues = false;
JsConfig.ExcludeDefaultValues = false;
JsConfig<Guid>.SerializeFn = guid => guid.ToString();
var tt = new { Name="Fred", Value=Guid.Empty, Value2=Guid.NewGuid() };
var test = JSON.stringify(tt);
Console.WriteLine(test);
```

Gives

`{"Name":"Fred","Value2":"07a2d8c0-48ad-4e72-b6f3-4fec81c36a1d"}`

So the presence of a SerializeFn seems to make it ignore the config settings so it's impossible to generate the empty Guid.
The same bug applies to numbers, so if (like us) you reformat all Double to three decimal places they are omitted if zero, which is wrong.

Has anyone found a workaround for this?

Comment: This is interesting find. Any comments @mythz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stepping through the source, it appears you need to explicitly call out what `Type`s you want to include the default value for if there is a `SerializeFn` for that `Type`. [Source reference](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/blob/d7829b054bba65a43c48b842d579d7820f8891f3/src/ServiceStack.Text/Common/WriteType.cs#L152). Note the `JsConfig<Guid>.IncludeDefaultValue = true;` line below.

---

**Example Source**

```
JsConfig.Reset();
JsConfig.IncludeNullValues = false;
JsConfig.ExcludeDefaultValues = false;
JsConfig<Guid>.SerializeFn = guid => guid.ToString();
JsConfig<Guid>.IncludeDefaultValue = true;
var tt = new { Name = "Fred", Value = Guid.Empty, Value2 = Guid.NewGuid() };
var test = tt.ToJson();
Console.WriteLine(test);
```

**Output**

```
{"Name":"Fred","Value":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000","Value2":"b86c4a18-db07-42f8-b618-6263148219ad"}
```

---

**Your problem statement**: [Gistlyn](https://gistlyn.com/?gist=22731c29d5e1ddbf2c3b840f260c308f): Note how it **does not** return the default GUID in the console.

**The answer proposed above**: [Gistlyn](https://gistlyn.com/?gist=f690dbe0aefd4a846785d6c1d87f154c): Notice how it **does** return the default GUID in the console.

Comment: Hmm, interesting, and nice find!
It's a pain that the global features don't work, but useful in that the option can be overridden on a per-type basis.
Thanks for that, I'll check it out tomorrow.

Comment: Hang on, you have
`JsConfig.ExcludeDefaultValues = false;`
so it never excludes default values anyway.

In fact, if you return a default GUID value and use `JsConfig<Guid>.IncludeDefaultValue = false` it still incorrectly returns it.

Comment: @JSobell: I took your exact "failing" question and just added the `JsConfig<Guid>.IncludeDefaultValue = true;`. Not sure where your confusion is here. I've updated the answer to include two Gistlyn's that show the before and after.

Comment: I *think* you're completely correct.
I've just tried reworking everything, and apart from the fact Gistlyn seems to give incorrect output compared to LinqPad, I suspect it might be working.
I think there are also issues related to JsConfig.Reset(), because it doesn't remove custom serialization functions.
I'll try and reproduce the issues I was experiencing earlier, but the I find the existence of global options like this to be awful  when identifying issues like this.